# How do I create a fake object in unit tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a class e.g.

```
class MyEmail:
  def __init__(a,b,c,d):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    self.d = d
```

This is an example class but my actual class has a large number of arguments in the constructor.  I am using a third-party library.
Now what I want to do is to pass these class instances to a method in Python but I want to mock these objects.

E.g.

```
email1 = MyEmail() 
email2 = MyEmail() 
email3 = MyEmail() 
method_under_test([email1, email2, email3])
```

Is there a library in Python that can help me mock these objects instead of creating these objects myself?

Comment: https://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html

Comment: Python has a unittest package, that has a [mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) included.

Comment: How will you mock the objects for my method using mock?